# How to get IDs of my batch update SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the IDs of affected rows on my batch update? As I'm trying to insert on table tbl.history of all the update/transactions.

Below is my sample table:

```
table tbl.myTable
+------+-----------+------------+
|  ID  |   Amount  |    Date    |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  1   |    100    | 01/01/2019 |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  2   |    200    | 01/02/2019 |
+------+-----------+------------+  
|  3   |    500    | 01/01/2019 |
+------+-----------+------------+  
|  5   |    500    | 01/05/2019 |
+------+-----------+------------+
```

Here's my batch update query:

```
Update tbl.myTable set Amount = 0 where Date = '01/01/2019'
```

with the query it will update/affect the two data with ID 1 and 3. How can I get those ID to insert it in another table (tbl.history)?

Comment: Use `TRIGGERS` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Juan, I have to disagree with you on this point. The request is fairly simple and one-off, so the current existing answers solve this in a tidier and faster way than a trigger, imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause. It provides you with a "table" named `deleted` which contains the values before the update, and a "table" named `inserted` which contains the new values.

So, you can run

```
Update tbl.myTable set Amount = 0
output inserted.*,deleted.*
where Date = '01/01/2019'
```

To understand how it works, succeeding this, you can now create a temporary table and `OUTPUT` the fields you want `INTO` it:

```
Update tbl.myTable set Amount = 0
output inserted.*,deleted.* into temp_table_with_updated
where Date = '01/01/2019'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `OUTPUT`

```
declare @outputIDs as TABLE
(
   ID int
)

Update tbl.MyTable Set [Amount] = 0
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID into @outputIDs
WHERE [Date] = '01/01/2019'
```

The `@outputIDs` table will have the two updated IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a caching mechanism (table variable, cte etc)

```
declare @temp table (id int)
insert into @temp select id from tbl.myTable where Date = '01/01/2019'
update tbl.myTable set Amount=0 where id in (select id from @temp)
-- do more stuff with the id's
```